# real analysis Basic real analysis proof limit point

Tags: real-analysis

> $$A_n = (-1)^n \left(\frac{\sqrt 2 \;n}{n+1}\right),\;\; n = 1, 2, 3, \ldots$$

My question is to find the limit point of this equation

I'm still not very good concepted with limited point.

This equation is alternating -1 and 1 and converge to $\sqrt 2$.

So can you say $\sqrt 2$ is the limited point?

If it is not what is the difference between limited point and limit?

How to find limit points of $A_n$ ?