# Is $(-\infty,3]\cap(0,1)^c\cap[-1,\infty)$ closed? Open? What are interior points?

Tags: real-analysis

> $$\text{Let }\;\;A_1 = (-\infty, 3]\cap (0, 1)^c \cap [-1, \infty), \quad A_2 = \left\{(-1)^n \frac {\sqrt 2\,n}{n+1}: n = 1, 2, \ldots\right\}$$
>
> Is $A_1$ open? Is $A_1$ closed? Find interior points of $A_1$. Find limit points of $A_2$.

1) I think first answer is not opened and closed, and I'm not sure how to find interior points.

2) $A_2$ converges to $\sqrt2$, so can you say $\sqrt2$ is the limit point of $A_2$?
What is the difference between "limit point" and "limit"? And how to find limit points of $A_2$?

Comment: There's some ambiguity in your equation because of formatting issues. Please see [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for information about typesetting mathematics at this site.

Comment: With respect to formatting issues: For example, does root(2)n  mean $\sqrt 2 \,n$ in the numerator, or do you mean to say simply "the square root of $n$": $\sqrt n$?

Comment: Please let me know if I've reformatted your question as you intended.

Comment: Is this post related to [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/529767/real-analysis-basic-real-analysis-proof-limit-point)?! Please don't re-post extremely similar questions, particularly don't do so using different user accounts. That's considered a abuse of this site. Edit your original post, address comments, wait for an answer. If you have additional related questions, indicate so in the original post.  In the previous post, you've failed to answer follow up questions in the comments! We cannot help unless you interact when those of us who want to help ask questions of you.

Comment: Also: Please cite the source of $(4):$ your posted image, prior to my formatting the image to be self-contained text in this post.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Maths.SE and thank you for your question! Please do not ask multiple questions in one post. It makes your post less valuable to future visitors, and it becomes harder to describe everything in the title. Also, please verify that I haven't changed the meaning of your post with my edit. You can get back to me by including `@Lord_Farin` in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The subsequence made of the even numbered terms converges to $\sqrt2$. The subsequence made of the odd numbered terms converges to $-\sqrt2$. The full sequence is made of even and odd numbered terms only.

Hence the set of limit points is $\{-\sqrt2,\sqrt2\}$. In particular, the full sequence $(A_n)$ diverges.

**Edit:** The second part of the merged question modifies the former question, to which the above was answering, since it replaces a sequence by a set. The first part of the merged question is completely unrelated to the former question (and for the life of me I cannot understand why the two parts are in the same question). The goal of the new first part is to make the student manipulate notions of topology in a simple case. Here $A_1$ is a disjoint union of a reduced number of intervals. Once this is realized, the answers to the three questions asked in the new first part  become direct.

Comment: This question has been merged. I want to let you know in case you want to add to your answer.